# Expressing maximum and minimum as $\frac12(x+y)\pm\frac12|x-y|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

I'm looking at ways to get the max/min value of two numbers without using conditional statements, I found these two functions:

```
int Max(int x, int y)
{
    return (float)(x + y) / 2.0 + abs((float)(x - y) / 2);
}

int Min(int x, int y)
{
    return (float)(x + y) / 2.0 - abs((float)(x - y) / 2);
}
```

While they do work, what is the mathematical reason/proof behind them? *why* do they work?

In mathematical notation:

$$\max(x,y)=\frac12(x+y)+\frac12|x-y|$$
$$\min(x,y)=\frac12(x+y)-\frac12|x-y|$$

Comment: If you choose $x>y$ then you see $$max(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)+\frac{1}{2}|x-y|=\\ \frac{1}{2}(x+y)+\frac{1}{2}(x-y)=\\ \frac{1}{2}(x+x)=x$$ and so this for $y>x$ ,also for min function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume that $x>y$. Then, $$\max(x,y)=\frac12(x+y)+\frac12|x-y|=\frac12(x+y)+\frac12(x-y)=x.$$

Similarly, assuming $x>y$, then,
$$\min(x,y)=\frac12(x+y)-\frac12|x-y|=\frac12(x+y)-\frac12(x-y)=y.$$

This is what you should expect, seeing as though $|x-y|=x-y$ for $x>y$.