# Min function defination

Tags: functions

Why can I not write the min function in equation form of a and b or can I because equation only fails when a becomes equal to b

$min(a, b) = \frac{a}{2}(1-\frac{a-b}{|a-b|}) + \frac{b}{2}(1+\frac{a-b}{|a-b|})$

Comment: At least, you’re missing a factor $1/2$.

Comment: added 1/2 forgot about it

Comment: @MartinR no because in program, I can check sign bit and can compute min, My concern is using it in a mathematical proof.

Comment: Then what is your question? Your formula is correct if $a \ne b$, and it is undefined if $a=b$.

Comment: @MartinR using min function in form of an equation, so I can simplify and proof, without checking every case manually.

Comment: $\min(x,y)=\frac12(x+y)-\frac12|x-y|$ is such an equation, as demonstrated in the Q&A that I mentioned.

Comment: @MartinR Actually [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540750/expressing-maximum-and-minimum-as-frac12xy-pm-frac12x-y) is right on every case I checked but I did not understood the logic of it.

Comment: @MartinR thank a lot understood the logic, it pretty good logic